# Homestead last 1 min to load my app in local

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm using laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 0.4.4) with a MacBook Pro ( 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7,16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3)

I have 3 projects, 2 of them work fine. The last one lasts 1 minute to load each page.

I tried to destroy my VM, using NFS, monitor my resources, but none of that is working.

Thing is my team is also working in homestead in the same kind of laptop, with the same project, and they have don't have this issue.

So... I have not many ideas about how to do it...

Any idea why is it happening and how to fix it???

Comment: Sounds like you are provisioning too much memory to all 3 projects

Comment: I personally use 1 homestead / vagrant instance and just switch between active projects with the `serve` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using NFS, and is Enabled in your Homestead.yaml

as such

     `folders:
        - map: "C:/Users/USER/Code/project"
          to: "/home/vagrant/project"
          type: nfs
          mount_options: [nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime]`

Next thing to do is configure your Homestead.rb

`Register All Of The Configured Shared Folders
    settings["folders"].each do |folder|
        config.vm.synced_folder folder["map"], folder["to"],
            id: folder["map"],
        :nfs => true,
        :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']
end`

Lastly to Apply Changes do `vagrant up --provision`

Assuming your vagrant is halted

but make sure your back up your existing data in your database...

Let me know if it work

Comment: I didn't edit Homestead.rb, but I now load my site in 15 sec. Great gain, should I gain more editing Homestead.rb?

Comment: You need to add that part to map all the folders in your NFS... It will load faster if you do that mine is loading 1 sec

Comment: dont forget to provision it again, if you edit your homestead.rb thanks

Comment: tx for your help! it is much better